# Accessing the previous object value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, file

I have a program where there is a thread running which is listening to messages coming into an event handler.

Based on the input it needs to read a specific file but it should not be reading simultaneously. So for example if I pass in file1 to read. It starts reading that file and I set reading_status to True.

The reading takes 1 min and within that time if the a read for file2 is requested then it should check if the previous read is True or False. If reading_status is True then it should exit and not perform the read of File2.

```
from file_reader import FileReader

def init(cls):
    cls.file_manager = FileReader()


def read_file(cls, file_name):
    if cls.file_manager.is_reading:
        logging.info('Reading is already active')
        return
    # Code for start reading
    cls.file_manager.reading_op(file_name)
```

```
class FileReader:
   _file_name = None
   _status = None
   _reading_status = None 
   
   def __init__(self, file_name):
       self.file_name = file_name

   def reading_op(self, file_name):
       # Code for file read
       self._reading_status = True

   def is_reading(self):
       return self._reading_status
```

Is my approach correct? How can i get the status for file1 if it is still being read when the file2 has be asked for reading?

Comment: What is your problem? Exactly. Stack trace please. If you want to ask for a code review then probably [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) SO forum is better for such a question.

Comment: I am not sure how to know if the previous file read operation is still running or finished when the file2 has to start getting read.

Comment: You may want to read on [Semaphores](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Use a mutex to do that. In Python, you can use [`threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock).

Acquire the lock when you start reading the file, release it after. If another thread wants to read the file, it must try to acquire the lock, which is already held, so it will fail (if provided the argument `blocking=False`) by returning `False` instead of True.

This is the stadard way to do simple inter-thread coordination.
@sophros recommended Semaphores which are not as much approcpriate than locks to your problem (a lock being a special case of Semaphore for N=1).